# How can I make https://code.google.com/p/bluez-tools/ without reference errors in Linux Mint 15?

Tags: linux-mint, compiling

I'm trying to make https://code.google.com/p/bluez-tools/. Configure seems to have found the headers. I have obexd-client package installed and BlueZ 4.101.

This is my first experiment at compiling a Linux C application.

Why won't it compile?

```
obexclient_session.c:(.text+0x202): undefined reference to `g_free'
obexclient_session.c:(.text+0x20e): undefined reference to `g_object_unref'
obexclient_session.c:(.text+0x21b): undefined reference to `g_free'
obexclient_session.c:(.text+0x228): undefined reference to `g_object_unref'
obexclient_session.c:(.text+0x239): undefined reference to `g_type_check_class_cast'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing libraries. You need to make sure that:

1. You have the required libraries `bluez` and `obexd` installed on your system.

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev libopenobex1-dev libopenobex1
   ```

   **NOTE:** There might be others but those seem to be the obvious ones. You can find additional libraries using the command `apt-cache search <string>` where `<string>` can be things like `obex` or `bluez`.
2. They are at the minimum required versions, bluez-4.69 and obexd-0.30.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that glib is missing (g_free, g_object_unref, etc are provided by glib)

`$ sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev` on debian like system